# Omniture not capturing iPad app data

Tags: ios, tracking, adobe-analytics

I am using Omniture in my iPad application to capture the data. I am using the ADMS library which can be downloaded from this page:

https://developer.omniture.com/en_US/gallery/app-measurement-for-ios

The library/download contains the TrackingHelper classes which can be used to capture data. Inside my AppDelegate I call the following method:

```
 // enable omniture tracking
    [TrackingHelper configureAppMeasurement];
```

The configureAppMeasurement method is suppose to capture the life cycle metrices but it does nothing. It only captures me as a unique visitor and that is it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the AutoTracking of lifecycle metrics in TrackingHelper.m

In TrackingHelper.m there should be the 4 auto tracking options already included. Just uncomment the one you want to use. If they are not there, then include one of these options:

To enable only LifeCycle auto tracking (this should be the default option), use:

```
[measurement setAutoTrackingOptions:ADMS_AutoTrackOptionsLifecycle];
```

To enable LifeCycle and navigation tracking, use:

```
[measurement setAutoTrackingOptions:ADMS_AutoTrackOptionsLifecycle | ADMS_AutoTrackOptionsNavigation];
```

To enable only Navigation auto tracking, use:

```
[measurement setAutoTrackingOptions:ADMS_AutoTrackOptionsNavigation];
```

To fully disable all auto tracking, use:

```
[measurement setAutoTrackingOptions:ADMS_AutoTrackOptionsNone];
```